# combine airtable columns only if

Tags: formula, airtable

How do you create a column in Airtable that multiples a value in a record with a value in another record (different column) but only if a record in yet another column is checked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional [rollup field](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042807233-Rollup-field-overview). Depending on your exact use case, you might want to combine it with another conditional lookup field.

If you need more specific advice, please share some more details on your setup:

- what kind of field is that "column" you mentioned (record link, checkbox, formula, etc.)?
- should the field remain empty or throw an error if the condition isn't met?
- is your provisional multiplication targeting computed or user-defined values (important for optimization purposes)